# php mysql update query

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am creating an `edit_setting` page that allows users to update their profiles. I was able to update every field, but the field for the email address had given me an error.

**DUPLICATE entry for key email_address**

How to solve this error?
This is the piece of code that handles the email field.
If you want additional code let me know.

## account_setting.php

```
     $edit_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name= '$fname', last_name= '$lname', address= '$country', email_address = '$email', specialization_name= '$spec', interest = '$aboutme' WHERE user_id = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error());


<td><label for="email"><span class="Fields">Email Address</span></label></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email_Address" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /></td>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: you should really try to use mysqli its even easier you should listen to that guy up there ^^^

Comment: email_address is set as a unique index, check your code

Comment: @ moussa harajli  i did used the mysqli but i am new to mysql so i want to learn and if i get errors i want someone to help me and i did not get so many help in using mysqli as in  the mysql

Answer (score 1):

This means that there is constraint on the `email_address` field that is prohibiting multiple records for a single e-mail address. If it's a primary key, then you need to evaluate what field would best uniquely identify the record (surrogate key). If it's a unique constraint, then you can drop the constraint.

Comment: @ Polish Prince so  you mean i must make it not unique ?? so if i want to make it unique and i want users to update their email how to do it ?? or i can not ??

Comment: @user2205838 `unique` means that it can only exist once. I think what you should be doing is checking that the e-mail doesn't exist on the application side and maintain the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

**email_address** field is *unique* and you are trying to insert duplicate entry

Comment: so you mean i must make it not unique ?? so if i want to make it unique and i want users to update their email how to do it ?? or i can not ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a unique key on email_address. If this is what is desired from a data sanitation standpoint in MySQL then there is really nothing you can do other than adjust your code to handle such error cases properly.

If it is not desired to have email address in be unique for every record in your table, then you can change the index type to not be unique.

Comment: so tell me if i had not understand what you say .. it is preferable to not put the email field in the account setting to allow people to update it  ??

Comment: I am not saying anything is preferable.  You have to determine whether having a unique email address for each user record is important for your application.  If you need uniqueness, then your app needs to be aware of this and understand that if a user tries to update their email address to one that already exists in the table, the update will fail. If you don't need uniqueness, then change the index to allow for duplicate values.